# How to convert an array of strings into values (symbols)?

Tags: ruby

How can I easily convert

```
a = [ "b", "c", "d" ]
```

into

```
a = [ :b, :c, :d ]
```

and vice versa?

I went through [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html) but didn't find a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To iterate over an array, returning a new array with updated values, use [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map). That's the key method you need to know about.

I'm not sure what you mean by "converting strings *into values*", but objects like `:b` in ruby are called [`Symbols`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html).

You can convert a `String` into a `Symbol` by calling `to_sym`. (And vice-versa by calling `to_s`.)

So putting this all together, you can convert the array by doing this:

```
a = [ "b", "c", "d" ]
a.map { |letter| letter.to_sym }
  # => [:b, :c, :d]

# Or equivalently, there's a shorthand for this:
a.map(&:to_sym)
```

If you want to **update the original** array, rather than return a *new* array, use `Array.map!` instead of `Array.map`:

Answer (score 4):

you can call `to_sym` on each element in a map:

```rb
a.map { |letter| letter.to_sym }
=> [:b, :c, :d]
```

Comment: Even easier: `a.map(&:to_sym)` which is a short-form version of same.